# Sql Count Query for starting from a value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working with prime numbers and I find a prime number with this steps:
1-get the square root of this number
2-try division from 2 to this square root
I am recording prime numbers that I found before to my sql server database. (table name: Primes, column name:value, id:auto increment)

Now, this is my question:
I need the number of element between 2 and the square root number in my database. But if the square number is=20 and there is no record like 20 in my database because 20 is not a prime number. So I need 19 in my database and the counting the number of elements from 2. (in this example, 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19 so the number of elements is 8)
Which query can give me this number of elements?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you using sql to determine prime numbers? Unless this is for school or something this is just silly as the list has been known for centuries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course use `<=`.

```
SELECT COUNT(value) FROM primes WHERE value >= 2 AND value <= root;
```